# SDK23 arm64-v8a native library

Tags: java, xamarin, native

I have android (xamarin) program, which uses my own C++ program compiled as native library. On SDK22 and some Samsung devices all goes well, but on Huawei with SDK23 and arm64-v8a processor not. Application crashes with library not found exception.

Could anyone help me how to compile native library in Eclipse for ARM64-v8a? I am using `c:\android-ndk-r10e\ndk-build.cmd -j8` command with `APP_ABI := arm64-v8a` parameter in **android.mk** file. Output compiled library .so is same as with or without `APP_ABI := arm64-v8a` parametter.

Comment: The `APP_ABI` parameter should be in your `Application.mk` file, not the `Android.mk` file.

Comment: Libraries compiled for `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` should work just fine on a 64-bit ARM processor. The situation you describe could arise because you have some other native library that you have built for `arm64-v8a`. IIRC, if at least one of your libraries is 64-bit then you are expected to provide 64-bit versions of all your libraries.

Comment: Hi guys, that solved my problem. In Eclipse I created "Application.mk" file with "APP_ABI := all" in "jni" folder and that solved my problem. Now compiler creates library for all platforms and after linkink it to Xamarin, all goes well. Thank you, David